# (Dialogflow) How do I store the place info from Place API into intent parameters?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

```
conv.ask(`Fetching your request...`);
            conv.ask(new Image({
                url: photo_request,
                alt: 'Restaurant photo',
              }))
            conv.close(`Okay, the restaurant name is ` + name + ` and the address is ` + address + `. The following photo uploaded from a Google Places user might whet your appetite!`);
```

This part of the code is only showing the text response on the console. I want to store the info into intents' parameter values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter properties of your conversation are used for [parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#params) detected in your users phrase by Dialogflow. These properties are read-only and cannot be used to store values.

If you wish to store values for later use in your conversation you can use the conversation [context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview) to do so. Saving data can be done by setting the parameter field on a [context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-manage#set-rt) object.